# Array of pointers returning NULL from function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, null

I'm having difficulty tracking down a problem with pointers returning null in my node structure. I simplified the program to the most basic functions so you could see exactly where the problem is.

This is a basic node tree set up where nodes can be added to each other to create a tree like structure. When creating and adding nodes everything works fine.

I have a print function which prints the node name and the names of it's children as well and here is where the problem is. Whenever I pass a node to the function the pointers to its children always return null. However, I can access the children pointer don't return null when accessed directly from the parent they only return null when the parent is copied into the function.

I'm compiling in C on Linux Mint 19. I included the header, code, and a basic example.

----header----

```
#ifndef node_h
#define node_h

typedef struct Node node;

struct Node {
    node* parent;
    node** children;
    char* name;
    int count;
};

node* create_node(char* name);

void add_child_node(node* parent, node* child);

void print_node(node* n);

#endif
```

----c file----

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"

node* create_node(char* name) {
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("Unable to create node %s.\n", name);
        exit(1);
    }
    n->name = name;
    n->parent = 0;
    n->children = 0;
    //n->map = create_stringmap();
    n->count = 0;
    return n;
}

void add_child_node(node* parent, node* child) {
    child->parent = parent;
    int count = parent->count + 1;
    parent->children = realloc(parent->children, sizeof(node) * count);
    if (parent->children == 0) {
        printf("Unable to add child node %s to parent %s.\n", child->name, parent->name);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (child == 0) {
        printf("The child node you are attempting to add to %s is null.\n", parent->name);
        exit(1);
    }
    // Add child to end of array.
    parent->children[parent->count] = child;
    parent->count = count;
}

void print_node(node* n) {
    //print_node_path(n);
    printf("%s\n", n->name);
    int count = n->count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%p\n", n->children[count]);
        printf("%s\n", n->children[count]->name); // Crashes because children are null.
        //print_node(n->children[count]); 
    }
}
```

----test file----

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"

// gcc -Wall node.c stringstest.c -o stringstest && ./stringstest

int main() {

//while (1) {

// Create tree
node* root = create_node("root");
node* branch1 = create_node("branch1");
node* branch2 = create_node("branch2");

// Add children
add_child_node(root, branch1);
add_child_node(root, branch2);

printf("%s\n" , root->children[0]->name);
printf("%s\n" , root->children[1]->name);
printf("%p\n", root->children[0]);
printf("%p\n", root->children[1]);
print_node(root); // Crashes because children are return null.
// This works since no children are accessed in the loop.
//print_node(branch2);

//usleep(100);
//}

return 0;

}
```

In the example the nodes children work fine when accessed directly the problem is in the print_node function. When the node is passed to it the children now become null aka 0.

This is the exact method I use to store and access arrays of pointers in other libraries. Perhaps I'm missing something simple. Either way it always helps to get an outside fresh perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the printing loop
this

```
    printf("%p\n", n->children[count]);
```

ought to be

```
    printf("%p\n", n->children[i]);
```

<sup>(Perhaps have a break? ;>)</sup>

---

Unrelated, but strictly speaking using the `p` conversion specifier with something else than a `void`-pointer is invoking undefined behaviour.

So better do:

```
    printf("%p\n", (void*) n->children[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I literally laughed at myself for missing something so obvious. I had been debugging this for hours and that slipped by me everytime. I think its time to take a break before I get back to work :)